# python-igraph: Get list of links between neighbors of a specific node

Tags: python, igraph

As part of calculating clustering coefficient, we need the number of links between neighbors of the node v. I am trying to implement such a thing and was wondering if there is a method specifically designed for such purpose. I know a simple way of doing it which looks like the following:

```
neighbors = graph.neighbors(v)
// Look for nodes where there is an edge between them
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
graph.induced_subgraph(graph.neighbors(v)).ecount()
```

?

There is also `graph.transitivity_local_undirected(v)`, which returns the probability that two neighbors of `v` are connected. So, it gives the number of edges among neighbors of `v`, divided by the number of pairs of neighbors of `v`.